# Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10

Tags: flutter, kotlin, debugging, android-gradle-plugin, flutter-dependencies

I am learning flutter and also building an app as I am learning on youtube. Until this point I have never seen this kind of error message I tried *pub clean*, *pub get* but it is not helping. I am stuck at this point what can I do to resolve this bug. Here is the error message:

*What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
> Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
> Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
> Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)*

I think the reason is is share_plus plugin. Because if remove it my project starts working correctly. However, when I install it again I got the same error message.

Please help me if you know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I already had this kind of issue and most of the time `flutter clean` command fixed it. Have you tried it ? You can also delete the `build` folder of your project

It looks like flutter has two versions of kotlin in its cache and doesn't know which one to choose.

Last solution would be to delete whole android folder and recreate it using `flutter create` command

Comment: I already tried flutter clean and flutter pub get. And as you suggest I did delete build folder and run again, but it change nothing. I think it is not a good idea to delete android folder. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: I didn't saw the line about share_plus plugin. Can you try to go manually to  local pub cache and delete all versions of this plugin that are cached and try again ?

Answer (score 0):

add this lines to app `build.gradle` this worked for me.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
constraints {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
        because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
    }
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
        because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
    }
}
```

}